# UIActionSheet UI specifications

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Can we control the font of the text displayed on a action sheet? Also can we change the UI specs for actionsheet buttons like height width? Or we should follow the standard given the UIActionSheet class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not documented. That's the issue. Using the current documented stuff, you cannot. Also read this:

[Is there any way to change the title font size in a UIActionSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919875/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-title-font-size-in-a-uiactionsheet)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the way that looks, the only robust and fully legit way to do this is to roll your own view classes to handle it they way you want from the ground up.  Because, sadly, Apple did not implement these classes in a way that is customizable.